# corrupt zip download urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to download zip files from measuredhs.com using the following code:

```
url ='https://dhsprogram.com/customcf/legacy/data/download_dataset.cfm?Filename=BFBR62DT.ZIP&Tp=1&Ctry_Code=BF'

request = urllib2.urlopen(url)

output = open("install.zip", "w") 
output.write(request.read()) 
output.close()
```

However the downloaded file does not open. I get a message saying the compressed zip folder is invalid.

To access the download link, one needs to long in, which I have done so. If i click on the link, it automatically downloads the file, or even if i paste it in a browser.

Thanks

Comment: Where have you logged in?

Comment: By logged in I mean, I have a user account. Perhaps if you try to access the link, it may not work. But I am able to click on the link, download the file and unzip it. However if I use the python code, the file is created, but gives the error. Since I want to download many files, I would like to automate the process. Thanks

Comment: So you haven't actually logged in via code. Clearly, you need to do that.

Comment: I am not sure if that is the problem. The file downloads fine. It just does not open. Maybe perhaps I need to log in using code. Unfortunately my coding skills are not so good. Thanks though

Comment: But are you sure what downloads isn't the login page? Try looking at the file in a text editor.

Comment: No it is certainly the file I want to download. I have tried downloading it using direct copy pasting of the link in a browser. Could there be an issue of the download being timed out. It takes a minute to download the file when I click on it, but request = urllib2.urlopen(url) happens very fast. Is there a way to ask it to sleep for a minute to ensure the whole file is accessed?

Comment: The more you say, the more certain I am that you are downloading the login page. Can you show me the first few characters you get when you open the "invalid" downloaded file in your text editor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58256/discussion-between-user1496289-and-daniel-roseman).

Comment: Sorry it did not allow me to add a long comment. I have tried to post first few lines from the text editor. <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: Which, as I keep noting, is the login page at https://dhsprogram.com/data/dataset_admin/login.cfm?CFID=32360106&CFTOKEN=63191756 .

Answer (score 3):

Try writing to local file in binary mode.

```
with open('install.zip', 'wb') as output:
    output.write(request.read())
```

Also, comparing the md5/sha1 hash of the downloaded file will let you know if the downloaded file has been corrupted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however the file downloads yet it is still giving me the same error. Can you please explain what is the md5/sha1 hash? How can I check that.