# Zip file being corrupted while downloading using Python

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, zip

I have a link to a zip file, which on accessing via browser directly downloads me the zip file. However, when I download that using urllib, file gets corrupted.
I'm using below code:

```
import urllib.request
import zipfile

request = urllib.request.urlopen( url )
#save
output = open("install.zip", "wb")
output.write(request.read())
output.close()

archive = zipfile.ZipFile('install.zip', 'r')
archive.extractall()
```

I found one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016115/corrupt-zip-download-urllib2) on similar lines, but it's not answered and seems abandoned.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use `requests`? I've found the cleanest way to do this is as follows:

```
import io
import requests
import zipfile

r = requests.get(url)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
z.extractall()
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! Though couldn't understand what was going wrong with urllib.